# Xcode 14: "No such module Kingfisher" in ios

Tags: swiftui, xcode14, kingfisher

On run build or archive will show build failed and indicate the line of `import Kingfisher`.

I did `pod install` and `pod update`, it still cannot fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: There are a few possible solutions you can try:
1. Make sure you have opened the workspace file (.xcworkspace).
2. Try cleaning you build folder and deleting derived data.
3. If the above points are not working then run `pod deintegrate` and install it again.